# KernelSU module for /product partition

Tags: custom-roms, customization, systemless-root, custom-sounds, android-14

I own a Pixel 8 Pro which runs EvolutionX ROM;

I also rooted it with KernelSU.

Now I would make a module that replaces some UI sounds.

I noticed that these sounds are placed in

```
/product/media/audio/ui
```

I used this template

```
https://github.com/symbuzzer/MMT-Extended-Next
```

and made the previously mentioned directory structure, in the root of the zip file, but nothing changed.

I also tried to put that structure inside the system folder of the zip, with no luck.

What also do I need to try to make it work?